# Calling previous-buffer does not update the buffer-list so it breaks other functions that depends on other-buffer

Tags: buffers, window

I have a lisp function that relies on other-buffer which refers to buffer-list. Calling previous-buffer on a window does not update the buffer-list so it breaks the function.

How do make it so previous-buffer updates buffer-list?

[reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html)

**edit**

I have the following lisp function that toggles to eshell with current directory set to the file I am viewing and from eshell back to the 
previous file.

```
(defun eshell-here ()
  "Go to eshell and set current directory to the buffer's directory.
   If already on eshell, go to last buffer"
  (interactive)
  (if (equal major-mode 'eshell-mode)
      (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer (current-buffer) nil))
    (let ((dir (file-name-directory (or (buffer-file-name)
                                       default-directory))))
      (eshell)
      (if (not (equal (expand-file-name (concat (eshell/pwd) "/"))
                      (expand-file-name dir)))
          (progn
            (eshell/pushd ".")
            (cd dir)
            (goto-char (point-max))
            (eshell-kill-input)
            (eshell-send-input))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f1>") 'eshell-here)
```

The call to other-buffer relies on the most recently viewed buffer which is stored in the buffer-list.

previous-buffer and next-buffer does not update the buffer-list so I lose
the ability to get back to the file I was viewing from eshell.

The solution I have come up with is to call switch-to-buffer after previous-buffer/next-buffer to indirectly update the buffer list.

Do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "*does not update the buffer-list*" and, more importantly, what you would want to happen instead. *What is the ultimate behavior that you want?* So far, this looks like an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Drew I would like to be able to get back to the buffer I was viewing with previous-buffer along with the call to other-buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems buffer-list cannot be directly manipulated so modified previous-buffer to call (switch-to-buffer (buffer-name)) to indirectly update the buffer-list.

Comment: Note that if you only care about *interactive* calls to `previous-buffer` then you should *remap* the bindings for that command to a new custom command which does what you want. e.g. `(define-key KEYMAP [remap previous-buffer] 'my-previous-buffer)`